# How much time is required to cross the Niagara International Border?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, canada, pakistani-citizens, niagara-falls

I am Pakistani passport holder with multiple entry visa for USA and Canada. I intend to travel from the Canadian side of the Niagara Falls to the USA side and then continue on to New York.

How much time is required to go through immigration process at both borders?

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE. Why should you not be able to cross the border? How much time required for what? Stepping across the border, immigration formalities, travel (from / to where)? What is the "best" way for you? Fastest, cheapest, funniest? Please edit your question to specify all of these things. I am voting to close as unclear what you are asking until you edit to clarify.

Comment: How are you planning to cross the bridge?

Comment: https://bwt.cbp.gov/?com=1&pas=1&ped=1&plist=0901

Comment: There are three different bridges in the greater Niagara Falls area and each takes a different amount of time during different times of the day and different days of the week. It's never taken me more than fifteen minutes to get through, but I've heard from friends who commute from Canada to the USA it can get longer. As much as an hour or so at rush hour during a snowstorm. You can find stats and a lot of info here: http://www.niagarafallsbridges.com/

Answer (score 6):

It takes about 15 minutes to walk across the bridge. Unless it's peak season, there's hardly any line up.  As a non-US/Canadian citizen, you will have to go upstairs for fingerprinting.  If there's a minimal line up, this will take 15-30 minutes.  If there is, it could take a long time.